# How to run a thread that uses an innerclass?

Tags: android, multithreading, inner-classes, runnable

When clicked on the button on activity_main (button1) I would like to test the ChatClientService.

In the method onStartCommand i want to run a thread which uses the innerclass as runnable. This is were it goes wrong: the intent works (log shows aaaaa) and it goes into the run method (log shows aaaaa) but I do not manage to go into the innerclass. Any ideas? (sorry for the logs)

**ChatClientService.java**

```
public class ChatClientService extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  //TODO do something useful

    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        }
    }).start();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public class ChatClient implements Runnable {

    private BufferedWriter bw;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private boolean running;

    public void halt() {

        Log.i("DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD","DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD");
        running = true;
        try {
            bw.close();
            bw = null;
            br.close();
            br = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE","EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
        }       
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i("HHHHHHHHHHHHHHH", "HHHHHHHHHHHHHHH");
        try {
            running = true;
            Socket s = new Socket("<your pc ip>", 9999);
            this.br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            this.bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            String in = null;
            while(running  && (in = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.i("CHATCLIENT RECV ", in);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF","FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("GGGGGGGGGGGGG","GGGGGGGGGGG");
        }           
    }
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void TestChat(View v){
    Log.i("cccccccccccccccccccccccccc","cccccccccccccccccccccc");
    startService(new Intent(getApplication(), ChatClientService.class));
}
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="be.howest.mad.lab24.oef1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="be.howest.mad.lab24.oef1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<service
  android:name="be.howest.mad.lab24.oef1.ChatClientService"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="false" >  
</service>   
</application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: exactly what do you want to do in Thread? can you go deeper...

Comment: In my thread I would like to start the ChatClient (innerclass)

Comment: Do yourself a favour and save a ton of time.  Learn to use the debugger.  `Log` is mostly a terrible way to debug, as it is here.  With the debugger, you would find this in minutes.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    new Thread(new ChatClient()).start();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Getting closer now, going into the try-catch block now but stops at creating the socket.